# How to wake up a process blocked by pause()?

Tags: process, block

I need to block and wake a process using SIGUSR2 and SIGUSR1 respectively. Below here's my signal handler sub routine. How do I wake a process blocked by pause?

```
void sig_handler(int sig) { 
    static int i = 1;
    if(sig == SIGUSR2) {
    pause();
    }
    else if(sig == SIGUSR1) {
/* I don't what to write here */
    }
}
```

Also, I read somewhere pause() is not a good programming practice, is there any other means to suspend a process for some time?

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pause-Problems.html)

In general, doing a lot of works in signals is ... tricky. Some things are not async-signal-safe, and therefore it makes robust programming there a bit difficult. In your case, pause() waits for a signal to arrive, but since you are calling it from the signal handler, it is not going to work there (I think).

As to making the process sleep and resume on signals. Look at the page I linked above. The best way is to have the signal handlers simply set flags and have the main thread (i.e. in main() or in an event loop) react to these flags. As recommended by the page, use sigsuspend when SIGUSR2 is received to pause the process until SIGURS1 is received.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Use the 'kill' system call-

```
void sig_handler(int sig) { 
    static int i = 1;
    if(sig == SIGUSR2) {
    pause();
    }
    else if(sig == SIGUSR1) {
        kill(<pid of process to wake up>, sig);
        // make sure that process with pid has registered for sig
    }
}
```